# How to find $\sup(\{|x-y|_p : x,y\in B(0;r)\})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Just to clarify the notation and the question:

Working in p-adic space $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we have the norm $|x|_p=p^{-ord_p(x)}$ and we define the metric over this space as $d(x,y)=|x-y|_p$. We are considering the open ball $B(0;r)=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}_p : |x|_p<r\}$. The question is to find the supremum of the metric $d$ over $B$.

My work so far:

Using the [strong triangle inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongTriangleInequality.html) one can show that for any open ball $B(a;r)$ in p-adic space, $r\geq \sup(\{d(x,y) : x,y\in B\})$. So we get that $r$ is an upper bound. My guess is that $r$ actually is the $\sup$, since there are no other (obvious) candidates, but I am unsure how to go about proving this. One thought I had was to show that $r\leq\sup(\{d(x,y) : x,y\in B\})$, thereby getting equality. But I could not see how to show this.

Any help, hints, or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be aware that $|\cdot |_p$ is discrete. It means that $r$ may even fail to lie in the range of the $p$-adic norm! Indeed, let $m$ be the smallest integer such that $p^{-m} < r$. Then $$ B(0, r) = \{x \in \Bbb{Q} : |x|_p \leq p^{-m} \} $$ and you can easily show that $p^{-m}$ is the desired supremum (indeed, maximum) of the metric $d$ over this open-closed ball.

Comment: @sos440 : thanks for that pointer.

Comment: @sos440 : why do you say $p^{-m}$? If $r>0$ it is quite possible that there will be some $x$ satisfying $|x|_p=p^n$ for some positive power of p.

Comment: Since $m$ is an integer, $-m$ can also be positive. :)

Comment: @sos440 : fair point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$-adic absolute value takes values in $p^\mathbb{Z} \cup \{0\}$, which is discrete apart from the limit point $0$. Let $n \in \mathbb Z$ be such that $p^n < r \leq p^{n+1}$. Then for $x,y \in B(0,r)$ one has $|x-y|_p < r$, thus $|x-y|_p \leq p^n < r$. So $r$ can't be the supremum $\{ |x-y|_p : x,y, \in B(0,r) \}$. Rather the supremum is $p^n$ as $|p^{-n}|_p = p^n$ and $p^{-n} \in B(0,r)$.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty dumb of me not to think about the kind of values the norm can take! Thanks a lot.